# handling Button Event in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uibutton

[image: sren sort]

i created a Drop down class for popup a window on click button , that is work fine but there is a problem is that how can i handle its event that it return index (on popup of tableview which is selected for its own button) what i mistak there ? any one guide me what i will do for it ??

here code for that..

```
 -(IBAction)popupOnClikingButton:(id)sender{

if (sender == button1) {
    arrayData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Test1",@"Test2",nil]];
   dropDownView = [[DropDownView alloc] initWithArrayData:arrayData cellHeight:30 heightTableView:150 paddingTop:-3 paddingLeft:-1 paddingRight:-1 refView:button1 animation:BLENDIN openAnimationDuration:2 closeAnimationDuration:2];
    dropDownView.delegate = self;
    [dropDownView openAnimation];
    [self.view addSubview:dropDownView.view];
    return;

}
if (sender == button2) {
    [arrayData release];
     arrayData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Demo1",@"Demo2",nil]];

    dropDownView = [[DropDownView alloc] initWithArrayData:arrayData cellHeight:30 heightTableView:150 paddingTop:-3 paddingLeft:-1 paddingRight:-1 refView:button1 animation:BLENDIN openAnimationDuration:2 closeAnimationDuration:2];

    dropDownView.delegate = self;
    [dropDownView openAnimation];
    [self.view addSubview:dropDownView.view];
    return;
}
}
```

return index DropDownDelegate method is.. How Can i handle this event that which button for returnIndex ??

```
-(void)dropDownCellSelected:(NSInteger)returnIndex{

 //set for title that which button is selected here for Ex.
[button1 setTitle:[arrayData objectAtIndex:returnIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: The people here are not able to understand your question that's why you got down vote... improve the quality of your question.

Comment: your english is not understandable.

Comment: do not sorry, just rewrite the question.

Answer (score 1):

try to get button like this:

```
UIButton* myButton = (UIButton*)sender;
```

and compare this button with your desired button...........

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign a tag to your buttons. With this, you can use the tag in comparing to your buttons.